# How to display a javascript graph inside a modal dialog using JQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, graph, modal-dialog

I have a javascript function graph() which draw a dynamic graph and I wanna put this inside a modal dialog.
I wrote this:

```
function drawGraphinDialog(){
    $("body").append('<div id="graphdialog"></div>');
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#graphdialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    open: function{
                                      graph();
                                 },        
                    height: 600,
                    width: 400,
                    title: 'This is your graph'
                    });
        return false;
    });
}
```

but the modal dialog is empty. 
Where should I put the function graph() to draw it inside the graph properly?
Thanks for the help!

Edit: the graph has made with this library http://www.graphdracula.net/... so if I call this function graph() inside an html body page it draws this graph and I can actually see it.

Comment: The answer depends on how `graph()` (or `Graph()` - you have both spellings in your question) actually draws the graph.

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawGraphinDialog(){
    $("body").append('<div id="graphdialog"></div>');
    call graph() function and set its content to graphdialog div
    $("#graphdialog").html(graph_content)

$('#graphdialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 600,
                    width: 400,
                    title: 'This is your graph'
    });
}
```